# Запустить свою js функцию через точку

Tags: javascript, jquery, функции

Использую js, jquery

Написал функцию `contains(object, item, showCount)`, которая показывает, есть ли в строке или массиве `object` элемент `item`, а если нужно, то и возвращает кол-во повторений этого элемента, получив `showCount = true`.

И вдруг мне что-то захотелось эту функцию вызывать так: `Array.contains(item, showCount)`, или так `String.contains(item, showCount)`.

Есть возможность так вызвать ее? Если есть то как?)

Comment: конечно есть возможность. надо просто ...

Comment: Array.prototype.yourFunctionName = function() { // your code }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    console.log(this[i]);
  }
}
Array.prototype.myFunction = myFunction;
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
arr.myFunction();
```

Comment: Спасибо, а со строкой так получится?

Comment: Получится, если  немного переделать функцию